# How to show that $a_{n+1} = \frac{a_n^2 +3}{4} $ is increasing.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I'm not good at finding whether a sequence is increasing or decreasing. $a_{n+1} = \dfrac{a_n^2 +3}{4}$ is the recursive sequence where $ a_1 =0$

How to get the approach to do something like this?

How to prove if a sequence like $ a_n = \dfrac{n}{ \sqrt {n^3 +1}} $  is decreasing?

Comment: for $ a_n = \frac{n}{ \sqrt {n^3 +1}} $  if derivative is positive than it will be increasing.

Comment: There's no harm in considering $a_n$ as a function directly, is there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We first prove that $a_n\in[0,1)$, clearly $a_0<1$. Assume that $a_n\in[0,1)$ then : $$ 0\leq \frac{a_n^2+3}{4} <\frac{1^2+3}{4} =1\Leftrightarrow a_{n+1}\in [0,1) $$
This means that $a_n\in [0,1)$ for any natural number $n$ by induction.
We have  : $$a_{n+1} -a_n =\frac{a^2-4a_n+3}{4} = \frac{(a_n-1)(a_n-3)}{4}\geq 0$$ Then the sequence $(a_n)$ is increasing.

Why $[0,1)$ ? First solve the equation $x=(x^2+3)/4$ you'll find $\{1,3\}$ which suggests (not surely) that $1$ is a limit (if $a_n$ converges) then you continue work.

**Second question:**

Set $f(x)=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^3+1}}$, then $f'(x)=\frac{2-x^3}{2(x^3+1)^{3/2}}$, then $a_n$ is decreasing starting from $n=1$.

Comment: Yes this is actually what I wanted. The earlier section of the first problem was to prove that 1 is an upper bound. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A sequence is decreasing if, for every $n$, $$a_{n+1} \leq a_n.$$

You can prove that a sequence is decreasing if for every $n$,  you can prove  that $a_{n+1}\leq a_n$

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you only want to get a solution but a general idea. @5xum gave one: compare the terms directly, and here is the solution:

For the **1st** problem, what you have to prove is
$$a_n\le a_{n+1}={a_n^2+3\over4}.$$
This is equivalent to
$$(a_n-1)(a_n-3)\ge0.$$
Since $a_1=0$, it is easy to see that $a_n<1$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$, so the proof is completed.

For the **2nd** problem, @Satvik's idea is more easy to use than the previous idea. It's because in this problem, $a_n$ is represented as a *function* of $n$, while in the previous problem, $\{a_n\}$ is defined as the *recurrence formula*.